# Loops to skip tk.Entry if Null python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Ive been working on a time card calculator, and when posting some problems I had, people mentioned I should rework everything to make it shorter and more efficient.

In the calculator I have 16 `tk.Entry` boxes for `time_in` and 16 for `time_out` so 32 in total.
Before I was using a function that took each `time_in` and `time_out` box and individually converted them to decimal then subtracted the `time_out` from the `time_in` to get the `total`hours worked, then put the total for each shift into a `tk.Label`, then add all of the totals together and put the `grand_total` into a `tk.Label`.

To shorten this, I've been trying to write a `loop` to use instead.

I haven't written the rest of it yet, as I have been having trouble with this part.

I had it working before I added the `if` statement. I added it because I was trying to come up with a way to basically skip any `time_in` or `time_out` boxes that didn't have any input in them. Either skip it, or set it to 0.0.

So that basically if there was input, it would run the code below, converting everything to decimals and storing it in the correct list.

Also, if you notice, I only go up to `time_in3` and `time_out3` in the `time_in` and `time_out` lists. I only did that for now until I could get everything working then ill put the rest in there.

But ever since I put the `if` statement in there, I keep getting this error.

`in calculate
    totals_in.append(round(float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0), 3))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

I can't quite figure out why, as it was working fine before. I know there's probably some easy solution to this, but I know this is part of the learning process for me. I've got to have problems to learn from.

```
def calculate():

    time_in =[time_in1.get(), time_in2.get(), time_in3.get()]
    time_out = [time_out1.get(), time_out2.get(), time_out3.get()]
    totals_in = []
    totals_out = []
    grand_totals = []

    for time in time_in:
        if time == None:
            continue
        fields = time.split(":")
        hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
        minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
        totals_in.append(round(float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0), 3))

    for times in time_out:
        if times == None:
            continue
        fields = times.split(":")
        hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
        minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
        totals_out.append(round(float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0), 3))
```

This is all of the code if it helps any. Right now I have it so that it sets all of the `Entry` s to 0. But I feel like it will be smarter to do as I was saying above and either skip the box all together or set it to 0.0 if its null.

```
import tkinter as tkr
import tempfile
import os
import numpy
import wx
from wx.html import HtmlEasyPrinting
root = tkr.Tk()

windowWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()
positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)

root.title("Time Card Calculator")
root.geometry( "+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))
root.resizable(0,0)
root.configure(background='grey33')

labelfont = ('calibri', 35)

header = tkr.Label(root, text="Time Card Calculator", background="grey33")
header.config(font=labelfont)
header.config(fg="snow")
header.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

smallfont = ('calibri', 20)

firstlabel = tkr.Label(root, text="Employee first name", background="gray33")
firstlabel.config(font=smallfont)
firstlabel.config(fg="snow")
firstlabel.grid(row=1, column=0)

lastlabel = tkr.Label(root, text="Employee last name", background="gray33")
lastlabel.config(font=smallfont)
lastlabel.config(fg="snow")
lastlabel.grid(row=1, column=2)

startlabel = tkr.Label(root, text="Pay start", background="grey33")
startlabel.config(font=smallfont)
startlabel.config(fg="snow")
startlabel.grid(row=3, column=0)

endlabel = tkr.Label(root, text="Pay end", background="grey33")
endlabel.config(font=smallfont)
endlabel.config(fg="snow")
endlabel.grid(row=3, column=1)

datelabel = tkr.Label(root, text="Pay date", background="grey33")
datelabel.config(font=smallfont)
datelabel.config(fg="snow")
datelabel.grid(row=3, column=2)

inlabel = tkr.Label(root, text="Time In", background="grey33")
inlabel.config(font=smallfont)
inlabel.config(fg="snow")
inlabel.grid(row=5, column=0)

outlabel = tkr.Label(root, text="Time Out", background="grey33")
outlabel.config(font=smallfont)
outlabel.config(fg="snow")
outlabel.grid(row=5, column=1)

totallabel = tkr.Label(root, text="Total", background="grey33")
totallabel.config(font=smallfont)
totallabel.config(fg="snow")
totallabel.grid(row=5, column=2)

time_1_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_2_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_3_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_4_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_5_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_6_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_7_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_8_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_9_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_10_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_11_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_12_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_13_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_14_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_15_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
time_16_var = tkr.StringVar(root)
grand_total_var = tkr.StringVar(root)

zero = str(0)

first_name = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
last_name = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
pay_start = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
pay_end = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
pay_date = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in1 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in1.insert(0, zero)
time_out1 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out1.insert(0, zero)
time_1_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable = time_1_var, background="grey33")
time_1_var.set('')
time_in2 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in2.insert(0, zero)
time_out2 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out2.insert(0, zero)
time_2_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable = time_2_var, background="grey33")
time_2_var.set('')
time_in3 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in3.insert(0, zero)
time_out3 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out3.insert(0, zero)
time_3_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_3_var, background="grey33")
time_3_var.set('')
time_in4 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in4.insert(0, zero)
time_out4 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out4.insert(0, zero)
time_4_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_4_var, background="grey33")
time_4_var.set('')
time_in5 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in5.insert(0, zero)
time_out5 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out5.insert(0, zero)
time_5_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_5_var, background="grey33")
time_5_var.set('')
time_in6 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in6.insert(0, zero)
time_out6 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out6.insert(0, zero)
time_6_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_6_var, background="grey33")
time_6_var.set('')
time_in7 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in7.insert(0, zero)
time_out7 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out7.insert(0, zero)
time_7_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_7_var, background="grey33")
time_7_var.set('')
time_in8 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in8.insert(0, zero)
time_out8 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out8.insert(0, zero)
time_8_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_8_var, background="grey33")
time_8_var.set('')
time_in9 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in9.insert(0, zero)
time_out9 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out9.insert(0, zero)
time_9_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_9_var, background="grey33")
time_9_var.set('')
time_in10 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in10.insert(0, zero)
time_out10 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out10.insert(0, zero)
time_10_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_10_var, background="grey33")
time_10_var.set('')
time_in11 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in11.insert(0, zero)
time_out11 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out11.insert(0, zero)
time_11_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_11_var, background="grey33")
time_11_var.set('')
time_in12 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in12.insert(0, zero)
time_out12 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out12.insert(0, zero)
time_12_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_12_var, background="grey33")
time_12_var.set('')
time_in13 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in13.insert(0, zero)
time_out13 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out13.insert(0, zero)
time_13_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_13_var, background="grey33")
time_13_var.set('')
time_in14 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in14.insert(0, zero)
time_out14 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out14.insert(0, zero)
time_14_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_14_var, background="grey33")
time_14_var.set('')
time_in15 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in15.insert(0, zero)
time_out15 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out15.insert(0, zero)
time_15_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_15_var, background="grey33")
time_15_var.set('')
time_in16 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_in16.insert(0, zero)
time_out16 = tkr.Entry(root, highlightbackground="grey33")
time_out16.insert(0, zero)
time_16_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=time_16_var, background="grey33")
time_16_var.set('')
grand_total = tkr.Label(root, textvariable=grand_total_var, background="grey33")
grand_total_var.set('')

medfont = ('calibri', 30)

first_name.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=15)
last_name.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=15)
pay_start.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=15)
pay_end.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=15)
pay_date.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=15)
time_in1.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=15)
time_out1.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=15)
time_1_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_1_total.config(fg="snow")
time_1_total.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=15)
time_in2.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=15)
time_out2.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=15)
time_2_total.grid(row=7, column=2, padx=15)
time_2_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_2_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in3.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=15)
time_out3.grid(row=8, column=1, padx=15)
time_3_total.grid(row=8, column=2, padx=15)
time_3_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_3_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in4.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=15)
time_out4.grid(row=9, column=1, padx=15)
time_4_total.grid(row=9, column=2, padx=15)
time_4_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_4_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in5.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=15)
time_out5.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=15)
time_5_total.grid(row=10, column=2, padx=15)
time_5_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_5_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in6.grid(row=11, column=0, padx=15)
time_out6.grid(row=11, column=1, padx=15)
time_6_total.grid(row=11, column=2, padx=15)
time_6_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_6_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in7.grid(row=12, column=0, padx=15)
time_out7.grid(row=12, column=1, padx=15)
time_7_total.grid(row=12, column=2, padx=15)
time_7_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_7_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in8.grid(row=13, column=0, padx=15)
time_out8.grid(row=13, column=1, padx=15)
time_8_total.grid(row=13, column=2, padx=15)
time_8_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_8_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in9.grid(row=14, column=0, padx=15)
time_out9.grid(row=14, column=1, padx=15)
time_9_total.grid(row=14, column=2, padx=15)
time_9_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_9_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in10.grid(row=15, column=0, padx=15)
time_out10.grid(row=15, column=1, padx=15)
time_10_total.grid(row=15, column=2, padx=15)
time_10_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_10_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in11.grid(row=16, column=0, padx=15)
time_out11.grid(row=16, column=1, padx=15)
time_11_total.grid(row=16, column=2, padx=15)
time_11_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_11_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in12.grid(row=17, column=0, padx=15)
time_out12.grid(row=17, column=1, padx=15)
time_12_total.grid(row=17, column=2, padx=15)
time_12_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_12_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in13.grid(row=18, column=0, padx=15)
time_out13.grid(row=18, column=1, padx=15)
time_13_total.grid(row=18, column=2, padx=15)
time_13_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_13_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in14.grid(row=19, column=0, padx=15)
time_out14.grid(row=19, column=1, padx=15)
time_14_total.grid(row=19, column=2, padx=15)
time_14_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_14_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in15.grid(row=20, column=0, padx=15)
time_out15.grid(row=20, column=1, padx=15)
time_15_total.grid(row=20, column=2, padx=15)
time_15_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_15_total.config(fg="snow")
time_in16.grid(row=21, column=0, padx=15)
time_out16.grid(row=21, column=1, padx=15)
time_16_total.grid(row=21, column=2, padx=15)
time_16_total.config(font=smallfont)
time_16_total.config(fg="snow")
grand_total.grid(row=22, columnspan=3, padx=15)
grand_total.config(font=medfont)
grand_total.config(fg="snow")

def clear():
    first_name.delete(0, 'end')
    last_name.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in1.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in1.insert(0, zero)
    time_out1.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out1.insert(0, zero)
    time_1_var.set('')
    time_in2.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in2.insert(0, zero)
    time_out2.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out2.insert(0, zero)
    time_2_var.set('')
    time_in3.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in3.insert(0, zero)
    time_out3.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out3.insert(0, zero)
    time_3_var.set('')
    time_in4.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in4.insert(0, zero)
    time_out4.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out4.insert(0, zero)
    time_4_var.set('')
    time_in5.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in5.insert(0, zero)
    time_out5.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out5.insert(0, zero)
    time_5_var.set('')
    time_in6.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in6.insert(0, zero)
    time_out6.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out6.insert(0, zero)
    time_6_var.set('')
    time_in7.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in7.insert(0, zero)
    time_out7.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out7.insert(0, zero)
    time_7_var.set('')
    time_in8.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in8.insert(0, zero)
    time_out8.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out8.insert(0, zero)
    time_8_var.set('')
    time_in9.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in9.insert(0, zero)
    time_out9.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out9.insert(0, zero)
    time_9_var.set('')
    time_in10.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in10.insert(0, zero)
    time_out10.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out10.insert(0, zero)
    time_10_var.set('')
    time_in11.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in11.insert(0, zero)
    time_out11.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out11.insert(0, zero)
    time_11_var.set('')
    time_in12.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in12.insert(0, zero)
    time_out12.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out12.insert(0, zero)
    time_12_var.set('')
    time_in13.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in13.insert(0, zero)
    time_out13.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out13.insert(0, zero)
    time_13_var.set('')
    time_in14.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in14.insert(0, zero)
    time_out14.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out14.insert(0, zero)
    time_14_var.set('')
    time_in15.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in15.insert(0, zero)
    time_out15.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out15.insert(0, zero)
    time_15_var.set('')
    time_in16.delete(0, 'end')
    time_in16.insert(0, zero)
    time_out16.delete(0, 'end')
    time_out16.insert(0, zero)
    time_16_var.set('')
    grand_total_var.set('')


def calculate():

    time_in =[time_in1.get(), time_in2.get(), time_in3.get()]
    time_out = [time_out1.get(), time_out2.get(), time_out3.get()]
    totals_in = []
    totals_out = []
    grand_totals = []

    for time in time_in:
        if time == None:
            continue
        fields = time.split(":")
        hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
        minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
        totals_in.append(round(float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0), 3))

    for times in time_out:
        if times == None:
            continue
        fields = times.split(":")
        hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
        minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
        totals_out.append(round(float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0), 3))



def printer():
    print_var = (first_name.get(), last_name.get(), pay_start.get(), pay_end.get(), pay_date.get(), time_1_var.get(),
                 time_2_var.get(), time_3_var.get(), time_4_var.get(), time_5_var.get(), time_6_var.get(),
                 time_7_var.get(),
                 time_8_var.get(), time_9_var.get(), time_10_var.get(), time_11_var.get(), time_12_var.get(),
                 time_13_var.get(), time_14_var.get(), time_15_var.get(), time_16_var.get(), grand_total_var.get())
    printer_var = grand_total_var.get()
    print_file = tempfile.mktemp(".txt")
    open (print_file, "w"). write(str(print_var))
    os.st(print_file, "print")


button_clear = tkr.Button(root, width=15, height=2, background="deepskyblue", fg="black",
                          highlightbackground="dodgerblue2", text="Clear", command=clear)
button_clear.grid(row=23, column=0, padx=15, pady=5)
button_calculate = tkr.Button(root, width=15, height=2, background="grey33", highlightbackground="dodgerblue2",
                              text="Calculate", command=calculate)
button_calculate.grid(row=23, column=1, padx=15, pady=5)
button_print = tkr.Button(root, width=15, height=2, background="grey33", highlightbackground="dodgerblue2",
                          text="Print", command=printer)
button_print.grid(row=23, column=2, padx=15, pady=5)

tkr.mainloop()
```

Comment: first you should use `print()` to see what you have in variable and to see what string makes problem.

Comment: BTW: empty `Entry` returns empty string, not `None` - so checking `time == None` is useless. It should be `if not time:` or `if time:` which checks if `time` is not `None`, not empty string, not empty list, not integer 0.

Comment: @furas that was exactly what I needed to know. That fixed the problem I've been having.

Comment: someone can put text instead of time in entry (ie. "Hello World!") and then converting to time you can get `ValueError: could not convert string to float: "Hello World!"`. You should use `try/except` to catch it and skip calculations.

Comment: All of those entries can be created in a loop. Whenever you see yourself creating variables like `time_in1`, `time_in2`, etc, it's time to think about using a loop and storing the data in a list or dictionary.

Comment: @BryanOakley that's the next thing on my list of things to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone can put empty string or text like `Hello World!` in `Entry` and then `float()` can't convert it and you may get error like `ValueError: could not convert string to float: "Hello World!"`

You could use `try/except` to catch `ValueError` and skip this value

```
for time in time_in:
    if time: # check if text is not empty string
        try:
            fields = time.split(":")
            hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
            minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
            totals_in.append(round(float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0), 3))
        except ValueError as ex:
            print(time, "[ERROR]", ex)  # useful for debug and to see if there was problem with value 
            #pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the help. I finally got it working. I know I still need to work on somethings, like loops for my `tk.entry` boxes and stuff so I don't need to have all of these variables. But I still consider this a big accomplishment. 
Thanks @furas you were a big help. I know I've got a long way to go, but this is what I've come up with as the solution.

```
def calculate():

    time_in =[time_in1.get(), time_in2.get(), time_in3.get(), time_in4.get(), time_in5.get(), time_in6.get(),
              time_in7.get(), time_in8.get(), time_in9.get(), time_in10.get(), time_in11.get(), time_in12.get(),
              time_in13.get(), time_in14.get(), time_in15.get(), time_in16.get()]

    time_out = [time_out1.get(), time_out2.get(), time_out3.get(), time_out4.get(), time_out5.get(), time_out6.get(),
                time_out7.get(), time_out8.get(), time_out9.get(), time_out10.get(), time_out11.get(),
                time_out12.get(), time_out13.get(), time_out14.get(), time_out15.get(), time_out16.get()]
    totals_in = []
    totals_out = []
    grand_totals = []
    total_write = [time_1_var, time_2_var, time_3_var, time_4_var, time_5_var,
                   time_6_var, time_7_var, time_8_var, time_9_var, time_10_var,
                   time_11_var, time_12_var, time_13_var, time_14_var, time_15_var,
                   time_16_var]

    for time in time_in:
        if time == str(""):
            time = str('0:0')
        fields = time.split(":")
        hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
        minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
        totals_in.append(round(float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0), 3))

    for times in time_out:
        if times == str(""):
            times = str('0:0')
        fields = times.split(":")
        hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
        minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
        totals_out.append(round(float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0), 3))

    for (totalsout, totalsin) in zip(totals_out, totals_in):
        grand_totals.append(round(float(totalsout) - float(totalsin), 3))

    for (totals, label) in zip(grand_totals, total_write):
        label.set(float(totals))
        grand_total_var.set(sum(grand_totals))
```